# Menu nav single page

Tags: nodejs, jade, pug

Tengo este menú en nodejs (jade/pug)

```
extends ../templates/default

block content
  nav#colorNav
      ul
        li.green
          a.icon-home(href='#')
          ul
            li
              a(href='#') Generar
            li
              a(href='#') Cierre
            li
              a(href='#') Conteo
        li.red
          a.icon-cogs(href='#')
          ul
            li
              a(href='#')
            li
              a(href='#')
            li
              a(href='#')
            li
              a(href='#')
        li.blue
          a.icon-twitter(href='#')
          ul
            li
              a(href='#')
            li
              a(href='#')
        li.yellow
          a.icon-beaker(href='#')
          ul
            li
              a(href='#')
            li
              a(href='#')
            li
              a(href='#')
            li
              a(href='#')
        li.purple
          a.icon-envelope(href='#')
          ul
            li
              a(href='#')
```

y se ve de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que al darle click en el item generar se me crear por ejemplo un h3='Generar' pero sin salir de el menú, que quede en la misma pagina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ello tienes que usar javascript en el cliente, no puede ser solo usando html o jade.
Lo que tienes que hacer es asignarle un evento al `a` o a un boton, y generar un contenido dynamico con javascript o jquery o tu framework preferido.

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content')

function addH1() {
  // Hay muchas formas mejor de hacerlo pero solo para la desmostracion: 
  content.innerHTML += "<h1> Generar </h1>";
}
```

```html
<h3>
<a onClick="addH1()" href="#"> Generar </a>
</h3>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Te dejo el ejemplo en html para que puedas probarlo aqui mismo